# Getting the size of each type of the parameter pack?

Tags: c++, templates, variadic

After a long day of unsuccessful searching in the web for a practical solution to solve my problem, I decided to post my issue here, to clarify my goal I provided this simple code:

```
template<typename... types>
std::vector<SIZE_T> GetTypesSize()
{
    std::vector<SIZE_T> typesSizeContainer;
    typesSizeContainer.reserve(sizeof... (types)); 

    /*
     * What I want here is a mechanism to loop throw 
     * each element of the parameter pack to get its size 
     * then push it into typesSizeContainer.   
     * Something similar to :
     *
     *     for(auto& element : types...) {
     *         typesSizeContainer.push(sizeof(element));
     *     }
     * 
     */

    return std::move(typesSizeContainer);
}
```

When I call this function template in this code:

```
// platform x86
std::vector<SIZE_T> tempVactor;
tempVactor = GetTypesSize<char, short, int>();
```

The elements of the `tempVactor` should be `{ 1, 2, 4 }`.

Any suggestion or solution is considerable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would recommend using `std::array` for that:

```
template<typename... Types>
constexpr auto GetTypesSize() {
    return std::array<std::size_t, sizeof...(Types)>{sizeof(Types)...};
}
```

Comment: As @W.F. Mentioned your answer provided a practical solution which I was looking for, I’m rly grateful.

Comment: An excellent example of `sizeof` and `sizeof...` used in the same line of code.

Answer (score 6):

You can just initialize the vector with the unpacked sizes:

```
template<typename... types>
std::vector<size_t> GetTypesSize()
{
    return { sizeof(types)... };
}
```

[demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/EjWTT0XK9Xjvv4kQ)

Comment: I appreciate your help.

Comment: @AmraneAbdelkader also consider changing the result Type to array (it has compile time known size) this would allow the function to be constexpr...

Comment: @W.F. Right, it is an important point, ty for your proposition.

Answer (score 1):

There is another possible solution which illustrates how to solve the problem using *SFINAE*:

```
template<size_t N>
typename std::enable_if<N == 0>::type get(std::vector<std::size_t>& sizes) {}

template<size_t N, typename T, typename... Args>
typename std::enable_if<N != 0>::type get(std::vector<std::size_t>& sizes) {
    sizes.push_back(sizeof(T));
    get<N - 1, Args...>(sizes);
}

template<typename... Args>
const std::vector<std::size_t> get() {
    std::vector<std::size_t> sizes;
    get<sizeof...(Args), Args...>(sizes);
    return sizes;
}
```

Comment: Rokyan It is always a pleasure to see such alternative solutions, amazing.